# How to include function attributes inside a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class c():

    def foo(self):
        self.foo.loss1 = 20
        return(50)

prob = c()
l1 = prob.foo.loss1

print(l1)
```

> l1 = prob.foo.loss1
>
> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'loss1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class construction is not right here. So, you are trying to take in two input numbers and return their summation via method `foo`. Let's make a `Klass` that satiates your intent here.

```py
class Klass:
    def __init__(self, loss1, loss2):
       """Take input and initialize your class."""

        self.loss1 = loss1
        self.loss2 = loss2

    def foo(self):
        """Method that returns summation of the inputs."""

        return self.loss1 + self.loss2
```

Now use the class like this:

```py
# making an instance of your class
l1 = Klass(loss1=20, loss2=30)

# calling the foo method and printing the result
print(l1.foo())
```

This shows:

```py
>> 50
```

Comment: Kudos for getting the Ops intent, I thought they actually needed setting function attributes class wide.

Comment: Ehh, nothing to fear. Someone thought I should not show the masses how to do that for their own reasons, I don't take these things personally (well try to).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the OPs intent was different than the question, but the below should answer the original question.

---

Take them out of the method - you never actually called it so the attribute has not had time to be defined:

```
>>> class c():
...     def foo(self): print(1)
...     foo.x = 3
...
>>> print(c.foo.x)
3
```

No need for any instances here, just a class definition.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing several things wrong. The attributes will only be added when the class method is called and that can't be done until you've created an instance of it. You're also not adding the attribute properly.

Here's a version that works:

```
class c:
    def foo(self):
        c.foo.loss1 = 20
        c.foo.loss2 = 30
        return(50)

inst = c()
inst.foo()

l1 = c.foo.loss1
l2 = inst.foo.loss1

print(l1)  # -> 20
print(l2)  # -> 20
```